# How to update a table from a query result of another table related to the first one?

Tags: postgresql, update

Here is my attempt. What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

```
UPDATE table_a a 
  SET a.firstCreationTime = c.created_at 
FROM (
  SELECT created_at 
  FROM table_b b 
  WHERE a.id = b.id 
  ORDER BY b.created_at ASC 
  LIMIT 1
) AS c;
```

Comment: please always provide a [mre]

Comment: See my comment below - and also, (as with any database question), please include your **version** of PostgreSQL... Please also provide the structures of a and b - i.e. the DDL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_a ("id" int , "firstCreationTime" timestamp)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 days')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_b ("id" int , "created_at" timestamp)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '10 days')
> ,(1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20 days'),(1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30 days')
> ```

> ```
> WITH desired AS(
> SELECT "id", MIN("created_at") as "created_at" FROM table_b GROUP BY "id")
> UPDATE table_a AS a 
> SET "firstCreationTime" = "created_at" 
> FROM desired b  
> where a.id = b.id
> ```

> 

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table_a
> ```
>
> ```
> id | firstCreationTime         
> -: | :-------------------------
>  1 | 2021-03-11 17:13:08.966639
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5ddbb1969c8706b633e63beb30c8c9e5)*

Comment: yes, this is the syntax I found in the docs, but in my case id can occur multiple times in table_b and I only want to pick the row that has the least created_at value as stated in the query.

Comment: @MarkAdel Hi, and welcome to the forum! Do you mean the most recent "**created_at**" or the oldest "**created_at**" value? It's a bit strange though - a **created_at** should be a one-off per record - a "**modified_at**" would normally be used for something updateable?

Comment: Make a [mre] please

Comment: @MarkAdel i added an eaxample for you so that you can see, it will alnways help if you create a sampe for us

Comment: Thanks @nbk, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick (untested as I don't have any table structures or sample data!).

```
UPDATE table_a a 
  SET a.firstCreationTime = c.f_ca 
FROM 
(
  SELECT b_id, f_ca FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      b.id AS b_id,
      b.created_at AS f_ca, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id 
                         ORDER BY b.id, b.created_at ASC) AS rn 
    FROM table_b b 
    WHERE a.id = b.id 
  ) AS x
  WHERE x.rn = 1
) AS c
WHERE a.id = c.b_id;
```